# Integer Expression Expected, is it too large?

Tags: bash, integer

I tried to run this code, from aerospike's [start script](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-server/blob/master/pkg/tar/share/libexec/aerospike-start):

```
  mem=`/sbin/sysctl -n kernel.shmall`
  min=4294967296
  if [ $mem -lt $min ]
  then
    info "kernel.shmall too low, setting to 4G pages"
    /sbin/sysctl -w kernel.shmall=$min
  fi

  mem=`/sbin/sysctl -n kernel.shmmax`
  min=1073741824
  if [ "$mem" -lt $min ]
  then
    info "kernel.shmmax too low, setting to 1GB"
    /sbin/sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=$min
  fi
```

But it shows:

```
bash: [: 18446744073692774399: integer expression expected
bash: [: 18446744073692774399: integer expression expected
```

Is it because it's larger than `9223372036854775807`? Is there any workaround for this?

**EDIT** yes, it's because it's larger than than that number:

```
if [ 18446744073692774399 -lt 9223372036854775807 ]; then echo 1; fi
bash: [: 18446744073692774399: integer expression expected
if [ 1844674407369277439 -lt 9223372036854775807 ]; then echo 1; fi
1
```

Comment: What does `/sbin/sysctl -n kernel.shmall` tell you?

Comment: 18446744073692774399

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That number reported by `/sbin/sysctl -n kernel.shmall` is near the maximum for an unsigned 64 bit integer.  But Bash uses signed integers.  So it's not going to work.

Since the only use of the number is to check if it is too small, you should change the code to check the *length* of the number first.  If the number is longer than the threshold in base 10 digits, you know it is larger.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found a temporary [solution](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-server/issues/159) by checking the length first:

```
set_shmall() {
  mem=`/sbin/sysctl -n kernel.shmall`
  min=4294967296
  if [ ${#mem} -le ${#min} ] 
  then
    if [ $mem -lt $min ]
    then
      info "kernel.shmall too low, setting to 4G pages"
      /sbin/sysctl -w kernel.shmall=$min
    fi
  fi
}

set_shmmax() {
  mem=`/sbin/sysctl -n kernel.shmmax`
  min=1073741824
  if [ ${#mem} -le ${#min} ] 
  then
    if [ $mem -lt $min ]
    then
      info "kernel.shmmax too low, setting to 1GB"
      /sbin/sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=$min
    fi
  fi
}
```